# SSH.Net error "The connection was closed by the server: Failed to read binary packet data! (ProtocolError)"

Tags: c#, .net, ssh.net, ssh2-sftp-client

I use **SSH.Net** nuget package to connect to my partner SFTP Server and getting the error `The connection was closed by the server: Failed to read binary packet data! (ProtocolError)`.

Here is my code:

```
            var methods = new List<AuthenticationMethod>();
            methods.Add(new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(userName, password));
            var con = new ConnectionInfo(hostName, port, userName, methods.ToArray());
            var sftpClient = new SftpClient(hostName, userName, password);           
            sftpClient.Connect();
```

Howerver, these above code can connect to **my company SFTP**.
Additional, If I using FileZilla 3.62.2, I can connect to partner SFTP.

I don't know what is the difference between my company SFTP and partner SFTP and how to solve the problem. Please help me.

SSH.Net Version: 2020.0.2;
.Net Framework 4.5.2